# snprintf variable list doesnt convert enum to char*

Tags: c++, c, printf, variadic-functions

I have been doing a task to change the current logging mechanism in my CPP codebase.

The current one is something like a printf in which we can write

```
MYLOGGING(("Example Log :%s, Example Num: %d", String, Number));
```

Now as part of modifying it to the new logging mechanism, I want to get this complete output to a string using the snprintf(). For that I used a variable list for this.

The code was like

```
#define MYLOGGING(log_string,...) do { \
char buff[1024]; \
memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff)); \
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), log_string, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
MYNEW_LOG(NewlogParams, buff); \
} while(0)
```

Now, I am facing an issue.
The existing logging had many instances in which some enum values are printed using simple %d. 
In such cases, with this new code, it is throwing the following error.

> error: cannot convert ‘enumType’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘3’ to
>   ‘int snprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, ...)’

One obvious option to get rid of this is to give integer type casting for enum prints.

As that could be a tedious process, i am curious to know whether I can fix this in some other way?

Please share your views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By appending the `##` operator to the `__VA_ARGS__`, you are turning the format parameters into a `const char *`:

```
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), log_string, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

Change that to:

```
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), log_string, __VA_ARGS__);
```

and the conversion should work.

---

Actually, after looking at your question more carefully, I've noticed another problem. The `##` operator is indeed unusual and probably incorrect, however, the main cause of your problem seems to be the extra parens in the call to `MYLOGGING`

```
MYLOGGING(("Example Log :%s, Example Num: %d", String, Number));
```

If you compile a call to that macro in GCC with the `-E` flag to output the preprocessed source, you'll get this line expanded from the macro:

```
do { char buff[1024]; memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff)); snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), ("Example Log :%s, Example Num: %d", String, Number)); ....
```

You can see that the `()` are still there, messing up the call to `snprintf`. So remove both `##` in the macro and the extra parens in the call site.

Comment: Thank you glampert.
Things are fine when i changed it to 

snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "log_string",## __VA_ARGS__);


Now i have a confusion what is the diff between my old code and the one with "" for log_string.
Could you give an answer?

Comment: Read about the token concatenation operator: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html